# Pull data from an object

Tags: ssis

Using Script Task, I had stored data ie a Dataset or Datatable object to a SSIS variable of data type Object.
I wanted to pull data from this SSIS object variable which contains a Dataset object of data, and store it to a destination. This is possible in Script Task itself. I know. But how is this possible by using other SSIS tasks ? We pull data from source tasks by connecting to server and using sql command.

But how do we pull data from a SSIS object variable ? I want a solution , other than Foreach loop container. Without using Foreach loop container, what is the solution ? Because, I dont suggest Foreach loop container, since there are records more than 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK without using script task you cannot pull data from object variable. You can use a Script component as a data source and add rows to its output from with in the script.

Comment: But in this Script Component, how do we call the Dts Variable inside the code ?

Answer (score 0):

300 records is a very small number. If the Foreach loop works, then why not just use it? If you then have performance problems, and if you can trace them to the Foreach loop, then you should look into other options. But I have a hard time imagining that looping over 300 records is a significant problem. Of course you have more information than us, so maybe it really is an issue.